# CSS: Responsive Div's with margin and aligning?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a page that would have a few Div's which would be responsive.

I have created the divs and they are sort of responsive but I cannot get the margin right!

basically, I need to put some space between the divs so they are not stuck together.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/d7ndLptL/) is what I've done and this is the CSS:

```
.holder {
    width : 45%;
    height : auto;
    border : 1px solid red;
    display : inline-table;
    float : left;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) 
{
 #container {
     width : 100%;
  }
 .holder {
     width : 100%;
  }
}
```

I Can simply put `.holder {margin:4%; */OR ANY OTHER VALUES HERE*/}` but that would mean the first div would be pushed away from its original place which is not what I want.

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd use W3.css framework, it's pretty straight forward and compact: http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_ref_containers.asp

Comment: @odedta, never used that before! which one of those examples on their site is responsive divs?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_ref_responsive.asp - Try it: http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_ref_row

Comment: If you are going to look for a CSS framework, there are far superior alternatives, such as [Bootstap](http://getbootstrap.com) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

Comment: They are not superior in the sense of responsiveness, they might offer more features but it seems like he's on a learning curve so a smaller more compact framework should be fine for now.

Comment: One could google _top 10 css frameworks_ and see what are the best frameworks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about adding margin only on the right side?

Something like `.holder { margin-right: 4%; margin-bottom:4% }`.

Answer (score 2):

try replacing this class..

```
.holder {
    width : 45%;
    height : auto;
    border : 1px solid red;
    display : inline-table;
    float : left;
    margin:0% 3% 2% 0%; /* margin for the div*/
}
```

here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Sarathv15/d7ndLptL/2/)

Answer (score 2):

use    `margin-right:4%; margin-bottom:4%;` in `.holder`  and `margin-right:0` in media query

hope this will solve your issue

**[updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7ndLptL/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can set

```
margin-bottom:4%;
margin-right:4%;
```

to add some space between the divs

Answer (score 0):

Added right margin using `nth-child(2n+1)`

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/d7ndLptL/5/)